# Unzip file activity doesn't create any files but no errors found

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sftp

I have created a Tracking Extract which generates a .zip file (annoyingly, despite having only one export type) which I am trying to extract and move into my Import folder to put into a Data Extension.

I have created a File Transfer activity which first moves the file from the safe house into my `/import` directory, and the another file activity which unzips my file.

I've ensured the pathway for unzip activity is correct, the automation runs without any failures but no file is found in my FTP server (in any folder), there should be a `NotSent.csv` file.

**Edit: Added screenshots of unzip activity**
[image]
[image]
I have tried using static names such as `test.zip` as well to ensure theres no issues with timezones.

Comment: Try doing another transfer from the Safehouse, similar to your first File Transfer, but on `NotSent.csv` ( FT1 (move zip from safehouse | FT2 unzip file | FT3 move csv from Safehouse). Sometimes instead of going to the import folder on unzip, the files will end up back in the safehouse. If this is the case, you can actually contact Support to change this back to force them to end up in the import folder if desired.If the third FT fails and the file is not inside your import directory, I would contact SFMC Support and see why this is happening.

Comment: I've tried this as well, there just brings back an error on "FT3" saying the file is not found. I've created a case with Salesforce to see whats happening.

Comment: Sorry Deployment Failure, Can you please only redact the *sensitive* details. File and Folder paths should not be sensitive. I'll post a sample of our ZIP activity in my answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out after speaking with Salesforce Support this was a provisioning (business rules) issue, they have altered the rules and it is now working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this problem and solved it by running each activity manually to the base "Import" folder to confirm the files were being extracted and moved correctly.

The 3 activities needed to run a Tracking Extract process are:

1. Data Extract (Tracking Extract)
2. File Transfer (Safehouse to ExactTarget Enhanced FTP)
3. File Transfer (Manage File - Unzip Compressed File)

Run your Data Extract and File Transfer activities to confirm a new .zip file has appeared in the "Enhanced FTP Site Import Directory" File Location (also known as the "Exact Target Enhanced FTP" or the **Import folder** on your SFMC FTP).

Once you've confirmed the .zip file has moved successfully, setup your File Transfer Activity as "Manage File - Unzip Compressed File". In the "File Naming Pattern" field, put the exact name of the .zip file as shown in your FTP. Don't put any folder hierarchy before the file name, and select "ExactTarget Enhanced FTP" as the "Source File Location".

Once you've confirmed the Unzip activity works (and outputs the files to the Import folder on the FTP) you can customize the file names/locations as needed.

Here is what our activities look like:
First - move the file from the SafeHouse:
[image: Safehouse 1]

Make sure record the file name & location you use - eg: Extract.zip & Exact Target Enhanced FTP
[image: Safehouse 2]

Next, the activity to Unzip:
[image: ZIP Page 1]

Note the file name & location used is the same as above - Extract.zip & Exact Target Enhanced FTP
[image: ZIP Page 2]
I hope this solution also works for you.

Comment: This incurs the same problem, I cannot see the NotSent.csv file anywhere.

Comment: Confirming you are moving the NotSent.ZIP into the Import folder (from safe house) successfully?

Comment: Yep, the `.zip` file is there. File Transfer (extract) appears to work successfully, but I cannot see the file anywhere.

Comment: Can you please upload the screens of your unzip activity (removing any sensitive values) to your original question?

Comment: Updated original post now

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue like @Deployment Failure. Spoke to Salesforce support team and they said it's about this business rule for next time anyone having the same issues

> FILE_TRANSFER_LOCATIONS Business Rule as IMPORTSAFEHOUSE